# Is that possible to sticky a AWS Classic Load Balancer session forever?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket

This question is for the infrastructure pros, hope anyone reaches this text.

I’m currently using a setup with one EC2 instance behind a classic load balancer on AWS running a **websocket** express based server. I always planed to scale my application so I started it behind a LB.

Now I’m on time to startup another instance, but I have this major problem: **My websocket leaves a program running on the server - even when the user is out of the website - and return to show the program log to the user when he comes back to the website.**

Of course if the user connects to another instance on the load balancer, he will not be able to access a program running on another instance. So the only solution is to connect a user to the same EC2 instance, always.

I searched a lot but I didn’t find anything related, besides sticky sessions based on cookies. The problem of this solution is that it expires after sometime, and I want my user to access the program log again no matter how much time he spent without doing it.

So my question is: **Is there a way to sticky a user connection with the same EC2 instance using a AWS classic load balancer?**

In a way that new users follow the standard algorithm, going to be connected to the lower used instance, and old users keeps going to the same EC2 every new connection. Is that possible?

Otherwise I’ll not be able to scale my application delivering, because the main purpose of this server is to connect this running program with a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can customize CLB for that. But ALB just recently introduced [Application Cookie Stickiness](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/02/application-load-balancer-supports-application-cookie-stickiness/):

> Application Load Balancer (ALB) now supports Application-based cookie stickiness. This new feature helps customers ensure that clients connect to the same load balancer target for the duration of their session using **application cookies**. This enables customers to achieve a consistent client-server experience with **greater controls** such as the flexibility to set custom cookie names and criteria for client-target stickiness within a target group.

Thus maybe, if you can migrate from CLB into ALB, the application-level cookies could be solution to your issue.

Comment: I have zero knowledge on cookies. Is that possible that it expires if I do nothing for a long time and the user do not connect over several days?

Comment: @LeonardoRick I haven't personally used app level cookies yet, but in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/sticky-sessions.html#application-based-stickiness) they write the expire time is 7 days.

Comment: I needed something at least 30 days :(

Comment: @LeonardoRick What do you want to achieve? If you based all your setup on cookies, its not very good setup. Users can use different browser, device at any time, clear their cookies. You can't assume that for 30 days a user will be using same cookie. ALso what if your instances get terminated due to autoscaling or az rebalance?

Comment: I'm not basing my hole logic on cookies. That's exactly why I maded this question: Because I don't know how to persist a **user <--> ec2** persistence. I never planned to take care only of the browser. When my instance is terminated the program inside it is terminated too, so there's no problem to redirect the user to another instance.